# Get YouTube Thumbnails with JavaScript

Tags: youtube, css-selectors

When you hover your mouse over a video in YouTube, it display a short animated video (see attached screenshot)

[image]

I checked the network tab in dev console and the URL is of the format

`https://ytimg.com/an_webp/xxx/mqdefault_6s.webp?`

However, the page source code doesn't include these links. Is there a way to get the thumbnails for videos on a YouTube page.

Comment: Please add in your question the javascript code you're using.

Comment: Apparently youtube automatically generates thumbnails for every video. There are several different thumbnail urls and they are basically always the same - only thing that changes is <video_id>. Check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068344/how-do-i-get-a-youtube-video-thumbnail-from-the-youtube-api/2068371#2068371

Answer (score 0):

when you hover over a video it's GIF is created. You can create your own gif from any video using libraries like [gif.js](https://jnordberg.github.io/gif.js/tests/video.html)